# Java: How to reference a class var based on input?

Tags: java, string, class, parameter-passing, concatenation

I have a class "class Car" with 4 booleans:

```
class Car {
    boolean mWheel1 = true
    boolean mWheel2 = true
    boolean mWheel3 = true
    boolean mWheel4 = true
}
```

I also have a method "void removeWheel" that I only pass 1 parameter, the wheel number:

```
void removeWheel(int wheelNum) {
    // I need help with the following line
    Car.mWheel(wheelNum) = false
}
```

The last line is what I need help with. How can I reference the correct "Car.mWheel" number variable in the Car class when I only pass a number (1, 2, 3, 4) to my remove wheel method?

Keep in mind that I may add 100+ wheels to my car, so I want to dynamically concatenate the reference to "Car.mWheel(wheelNum)" instead of doing some if statement or static solution.

Comment: with if/else statement... or create array, which is much better.

Comment: `switch` is another possibility.
Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: This example screams "arrays! use arrays!.."

Comment: Thanks for the comment, in this case I do not want to use an 4 if statements, I want to concatenate a string, say for example if I decided to add 25 wheels to my car.

Comment: A better alternative to if/else would be to have a `boolean` array of size four.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
class Car {
    boolean mWheel1 = true
    boolean mWheel2 = true
    boolean mWheel3 = true
    boolean mWheel4 = true
}

void removeWheel(int wheelNum) {
    // I need help with the following line
    Car.mWheel(wheelNum) = false
}
```

Do

```
class Car {
    boolean mWheel[4] = {true, true, true, true};
}

void removeWheel(int wheelNum) {
    mWheel[wheelNum] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how class can look :

```
public class Car {

    private boolean[] wheels = new boolean[4];

    public Car() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            wheels[i] = true;
        }

    }

    public void removeWheel(int wheelNum) {
        getWheels()[wheelNum] = false;
    }

    /**
     * @return the wheels
     */
    public boolean[] getWheels() {
        return wheels;
    }

    /**
     * @param wheels the wheels to set
     */
    public void setWheels(boolean[] wheels) {
        this.wheels = wheels;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is the closest to what OP asks for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this trivial example you'd want to use an array or collection for your wheels. But there can be legitimate reasons to access a property dynamically by name, and you can do so using the reflection API:

```
void removeWheel(int wheelNum) throws Exception {
    Car.class.getDeclaredField("mWheel" + wheelNum).setBoolean(this, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrays above are the best option, but if you want to do it without changing the attributes:

```
void removeWheel(int wheelNum) {
    switch (wheelNum) {
        case 1:
            mWheel1 = false;
            break;
        case 2:
            mWheel2 = false;
            break;
        case 3:
            mWheel3 = false;
            break;
        case 4:
            mWheel4 = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```